# What's the mean of "instance" in Cloud Foundry?

Tags: cloud, instances

What's the meaning of "*instance*" in *Cloud Foundry*?

How can an app in Cloud Foundry can have many instances?

Comment: Cloud instance computing is highly dynamic, enabling users not to worry about how many servers can fit on a single hardware application without causing major slowdowns during peak hours. If performance maxes out, you can simply add more computers. Resources can be freely allocated to and from other computers by the software, enabling maximum utilization and helping to prevent crashes. So an app in cloud can have multi-instances

Answer (score 2):

We refer to each independent copy of your app as an 'instance' of the application. Each instance can be independently started or stopped, and if an instance should fail, the Cloud Foundry elastic runtime will attempt to restart it automatically.

If your application is designed for the cloud, typically following the guidance of the [12-factor app](http://12factor.net/), it can be scaled horizontally, such that there are multiple independent copies of your app, each running in their own container in the Cloud Foundry elastic runtime.

The Cloud Foundry documentation has information on how to [scale your app](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/cf-scale.html) once it has been deployed.